Matching Boxes with Drag and Drop in Jetpack Compose
I've been struggling for days with what might be a very simple task. I've searched every resource and watched every video online, but to no avail.
What I'm trying to do is this: There will be one empty box and one image on the screen, and when I drag the image onto the box, it will snap into place inside the box.
Actually, I want to create a matching game with multiple boxes, but in order to find a solution quickly, I'm trying to figure it out with one empty box and one image. Once I find the solution, I'll integrate it into my main application.
@Composable
fun TestArea() {

    var imageOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }

    var imageCoordinate by remember { mutableStateOf<LayoutCoordinates?>(null) }
    var blueBoxCoordinate by remember { mutableStateOf<LayoutCoordinates?>(null) }

    Scaffold { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding).fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .background(Color.Blue)
                .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    blueBoxCoordinate = coordinates
                })
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.game_icon1),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .offset { imageOffset.round() }
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
                    .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                        imageCoordinate = coordinates
                    }
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures(onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consume()
                            imageOffset += Offset(dragAmount.x, dragAmount.y)
                        }, onDragEnd = {
                            val isMatched = imageCoordinate!!
                                .boundsInRoot()
                                .contains(blueBoxCoordinate!!.boundsInRoot().center)
                            if (isMatched) {
                                imageOffset = Offset(
                                    blueBoxCoordinate!!.positionInRoot().x,
                                    blueBoxCoordinate!!.positionInRoot().y
                                )
                            } else {
                                imageOffset = Offset(0f, 0f)
                            }
                        })
                    })
        }
    }
}

When the dragging operation is finished, I'm checking for a match with the following line:
val isMatched = imageCoordinate!!
.boundsInRoot()
.contains(blueBoxCoordinate!!.boundsInRoot().center)

If you have a better method in mind, I'm open to suggestions on this matter as well."
If the isMatched value is true, I'm setting the 'imageOffset' value equal to the coordinates of the box. However, I'm not getting the desired result; the image stays anchored to the bottom right corner of the screen.
if (isMatched) {
  imageOffset = Offset(
    blueBoxCoordinate!!.positionInRoot().x,
    blueBoxCoordinate!!.positionInRoot().y)
} else {
    imageOffset = Offset(0f, 0f)
}

If the 'isMatched' value is not true, the image returns to its initial position.
I'm grateful for your help in advance.

Jetpack Compose recently added built-in Modifiers for drag and drop. Maybe you can achieve your goal using these. Check out this blog post for further information: https://canopas.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-using-modifier-drag-and-drop-source-target-jetpack-compose
